# egrepでワイルドカードの入ったOR検索

Tags: grep

以下のファイルから、egrepでサーバ名を抜きだそうとしました。

```
===test.txt===
tokyoAAsv01
tokyoBBsv01
tokyoCCsv01
tokyoAAsv02
tokyoBBsv02
=====end====

cat /tmp/test.txt | egrep '*sv01|*sv02'
```

これは上手くいくのですが、

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | egrep 'tokyo*sv01|tokyo*sv02'
```

とやると失敗します。
さらに test.txt から、AA,CCのつく行だけを抜き出したい場合、どのように書いたら良いでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

追記：
すみません、最後の、AA、CCのつく行だけを〜のところなのですが、説明不足でした。

```
===test.txt===
tokyoAAsv01
tokyoBBsv01
tokyoCCsv01
tokyoAAsv02
tokyoBBsv02
osakaAAsv01
osakaBBsv01
osakaCCsv01
=====end====
```

のように、他の拠点のサーバも混ざっており、AA、BBのパターンも10以上あります。
そこで、`tokyo` の `AA,CC,FF,HH` だけ、のような書き方をしたいのですが、
その場合、OR条件を入れ子にすることは難しいのでしょうか？
以下のようにやってみたのですが上手くいきませんでした。

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | egrep 'tokyo|AA|CC|FF|HH|sv01|tokyo|AA|CC|FF|HH|sv02'
```

後出しで申し訳ございません。

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> cat /tmp/test.txt | egrep 'tokyo*sv01|tokyo*sv02'
> ```

おそらく、`tokyo` の後に `sv01` または `sv02` が来る行を検索したいのだと思います。`*` は直前の正規表現 (単なる文字も含む) の0回以上の繰り返しですから、`tokyo*sv01` は `tokysv01`, `tokyooooooosv01` などにはマッチしますが `tokyoAAsv01` などにはマッチしません。

任意の文字列を表すには、`.` (任意の1文字) の後に `*` を置いて次のようにします。

```
 egrep 'tokyo.*sv01|tokyo.*sv02' /tmp/test.txt
```

または

```
 egrep 'tokyo.*sv0[12]' /tmp/test.txt
```

> さらに test.txt から、AA,CCのつく行だけを抜き出したい場合、どのように書いたら良いでしょうか。

つぎのように、`|` で繋げると、OR の意味になります。

```
egrep 'AA|CC' /tmp/test.txt
```

**追記**

> `tokyo` の `AA`, `CC`, `FF`, `HH` だけ、のような書き方をしたい

`(` ... `)` で括ることでグループ化することができます。

```
egrep 'tokyo(AA|CC|FF|HH)sv0[12]' /tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: 追記への回答ありがとうございます。まさに私のやりたかったことです！ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

既に回答が付いていますので補足など少し。

> **Repetition**
>
> A regular expression may be followed by one of several repetition operators:
>
> * 　　The **preceding item** will be matched zero or more times.

最初の正規表現についてですが、

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | egrep '*sv01|*sv02'
```

`*sv01|*sv02` の中の `*` における `preceding item` は空文字列("")になります。空文字列を何回繰り返しても空文字列ですので、結局は、

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | egrep 'sv01|sv02'
```

と同じことになります。

**追記**

> そこで、tokyo の AA,CC,FF,HH だけ、のような書き方をしたいのですが、

同じ文字の繰り返し(2回)、ということであれば以下の様な書き方も。

```
cat /tmp/test.txt | egrep 'tokyo([ACFH])\1'
```

※ 実際のデータの内容は違うとは思いますが、まぁ、この様な書き方もありますよ、ということで。

Comment: そういうことだったんですね！勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`*` は「直前の１文字の０回以上のくりかえし」なので `tokyo*sv01` は
- 文字列 `toky` があって、
- その直後に `o` が０回以上出現して
- さらに `sv01` がある
にマッチします。マッチパターンを例示すると
`tokysv01`  `tokyosv01`  `tokyoosv01`  `tokyooooooooooosv01`

欲しいマッチが `tokyo` のあと任意の文字があって `sv01` が引き続く、ならば

```
egrep 'tokyo.*sv01' /tmp/test.txt
```

でしょう。 `.` は「任意の１文字」です。

`AA` `CC` のほうはもっと簡単というか、まるっきりそのままのような気がします。
`egrep 'AA|CC' /tmp/test.txt` ってことだと思いますが・・・

元質問の編集を受けて追記

`tokyo` かつ (`AA` または `BB` ) かつ `sv01` ってことですよね？ `OR` ではなくて `AND` 。
可読性をあげるため、オイラなら `grep` をパイプでつなぐ、かな。

```
egrep 'tokyo' /tmp/test.txt | egrep 'AA|BB' | egrep 'sv01'
```

Comment: とてもわかりやすいご説明ありがとうございます。おかげさまで理解できました。